# SSIS Deploying Expression variables

Tags: variables, ssis, dtexec

I am planning to deploy a SSIS package on the production server using the command line prompt.
I am executing the following :

```
DTEXEC.exe /FILE "C:\SSISPackages\Rewards\ExcelMasterToRewardsExcel.dtsx" 
           /DECRYPT ssis 
           /CHECKPOINTING OFF  
           /REPORTING EWCDI  
           /SET "\PACKAGE.VARIABLES
[varExcelFilePath_Master]";"D:\SSIS\64bit\MIS_DownloadScheduler2012-11-29-07-00-03.xls"
```

The problem is that  I have another variable `[varOutPutExcel]` which is an expression variable which would take `[varExcelFilePath_Master]` and append datetime.

But How do I set this variable in the command prompt??

Comment: 1. You are not deploying... you are executing your package. 2. Expression are evaluated at the run time; you do not need to pass the value.

Answer (score 0):

Pass parameters like this:

```
Dtexec /isserver “SSISDB\MyFolder\MyProject\MyPackage.dtsx” /server “.” /parameter $Project::myparam;myvalue /parameter anotherparam(int32);12
```

More info here:

- [dtexec Utility - Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/packages/dtexec-utility?view=sql-server-2017#parameter)

For deployment , use deployment wizard by right clicking the solution if deploying to integration catalog. Dtexe.exe only executes the package, no more. If using a file store to store the solution or dtsx in a folder, supply that address to dtexec without ISServer option.

It is important to understand that expressions are computed when the package runs. But values can be passed for those expressions to use by employing parameters as shown above.